# Characteristic Polynomial of a Hermitian Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, self-adjoint-operators

I am reviewing some more advanced linear algebra before I go to grad school, and I came across this question.

"Does there exist a Hermitian matrix with characteristic polynomial equal to $x^4- 1$? If there does, construct one and prove it is one. If there does not, prove there does not."

If we take our field to be the complex numbers, then we have 4 distinct eigenvalues $1,-1,i,-i$, each with algebraic/geometric multiplicity 1, so we have a diagonalizable matrix (similar to a diagonal matrix) with a basis of eigenvectors for our vector space. So I though about the matrix
  $$A= \begin{bmatrix}
     1  & 0 &0 &0\\
     0& -1 &0&0 \\
     0 &0 &i &0\\
     0 &0&0&-i\\
  \end{bmatrix}$$
However 
 $$A^*= \begin{bmatrix}
     1  & 0 &0 &0\\
     0& -1 &0&0 \\
     0 &0 &-i &0\\
     0 &0&0&i\\
  \end{bmatrix}$$
So $A\neq A^*$.
I know that a matrix is hermitian if and only if there exists an orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors of T. So why does my example not work out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A square matrix is Hermitian if and only if it is unitarily diagonalizable with *real* eigenvalues. This proves that the answer is negative.

Comment: Is is reasoning correct then?
square matrix is Hermitian $\iff$

unitarily diagonalizable with real eigenvalues $\iff$

there exists a basis of eigenvectors with real eigenvalues
However, since the matrix will only have 2 linearly independent eigenvectors with $\textit{real}$ eigenvalues, there will not exist such a basis. Thus there will be no Hermitian matrices with this characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But it is simpler to say that *if* it was Hermition, *then* its characterist polynomial would have only *real* eigenvalues. And that is *not* the case here.

Comment: Great, thank you for the clarification.